# Why does junit behavior change when moving from java 8 to java 11 without changing junit version?

Tags: junit4, java-11

```
> gradlew -version
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 4.10.3
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2018-12-05 00:50:54 UTC
Revision:     e76905e3a1034e6f724566aeb985621347ff43bc

Kotlin DSL:   1.0-rc-6
Kotlin:       1.2.61
Groovy:       2.4.15
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.11 compiled on March 23 2018
JVM:          11.0.20 (Azul Systems, Inc. 11.0.20+8-LTS)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64
```

Junit version: 4.13.2

**Previously using Java 8 without issues.  Our only change is moving JDK (and deployed JRE) from Java 8 to Java 11. Junit and Gradle did not change.**

We have unit tests that run with each build, and integration tests that run using an optional gradle task.

We have some utility classes used *only* by our tests.

- Many are private inner classes.  Of those, some are implementing private interfaces.
- Some are public classes *used by* multiple test classes, but are not tests themselves.
- Some have overloaded constructors, which provides much of their utility purpose.

With Java 11, Junit now wants to treat all of those classes as if they were test classes, and complains that **(a)** the private ones are not public **(b)** the classes contain no runnable @Test methods, and **(c)** where applicable, complains that the class must have a single constructor.

This applies even to enums and interfaces! (Why in the world would junit expect an enum or an interface to contain test methods?!?)

Adding @Ignore for every utility *class*, including *enums*, and every utility *interface,* gets around the issue, though I do not understand why the behavior changed when *only the Java version* changed.

Here is an example of one of our integration tests failing, where in this case, UserManagerOperations is a private interface:

```
org.junit.runners.model.InvalidTestClassError: Invalid test class 'com.XXX.YYY.integration.support.UserManager$UserManagerOperations':
  1. The class com.XXX.YYY.integration.support.UserManager$UserManagerOperations is not public.
  2. Test class should have exactly one public constructor
  3. No runnable methods
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validate(ParentRunner.java:525)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:102)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.JUnit4.<init>(JUnit4.java:23)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.JUnit4Builder.runnerForClass(JUnit4Builder.java:10)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:70)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:37)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:70)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.createRunner(ClassRequest.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.MemoizingRequest.getRunner(MemoizingRequest.java:19)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:78)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor14.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:117)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor13.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:155)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:137)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:404)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Since I have a work-around, this isn't a cry for a fix as much as hoping to find someone who can explain (a) how/why junit's behavior changed without changing junit, and (b) how the changes are even remotely logical.  These changes (and it's requiring touching many classes), just seem illogical, though oddly required.  (Ideally, I would like to avoid touching so much code just to add the @Ignores, but I'll accept that if needed....but I really would like to understand what is going on.)

FWIW, at some point we will likely move to a later gradle version and to junit 5 or later since there are reflection-related deprecation warnings with junit 4 (though with java 11 they're just warnings), but with the amount of work moving from java 8 to 11 on a huge codebase, we need to take this in as small as possible, incremental steps.

Comment: We're using Java 17 and JUnit 5, what you described doesn't happen to us

Comment: We’re using JUnit 4 with JDK 17 without problems but with Eclipse’s runner and with Jenkins, both equally successful. Your stack trace indicates that the runner is triggered by a Gradle specific front-end. Maybe that’s the cause of the problem.

Comment: That does seem to be the case, @Holger, but I'm still baffled as to how/why since we did not change gradle versions.  I am looking into the possibility of upgrading gradle, but that might be too much to add all at once.

The errors are more like warnings -- everything builds and tests seem run fine, but getting 50+ call stack dumps during a build is ugly to say the least.  At this point, I'd be happy if I could suppress the stack traces and just get the text above them.

Comment: Update: Moving to gradle 5.0 wasn't as big of a task as I expected. That solved this problem when building from the command line.  No more 50+ of these stack traces.  Oddly, when building from within IntelliJ, I still get one.  I don't know how 49 or so would go away and one remain, and only within IJ, but I'm not too worried about it.  Thank you @Holger for pointing out it could be specific to gradle.

Comment: ...and that one in IntelliJ went away after restarting it.  :-)